# Safari cookies destroyed on tab selection

Tags: jquery, ipad, session, cookies

I have an iPad that, after I've logged into my web application, a session cookie is being deleted.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Log into web application that uses session cookies
2. Open a new tab to anything else
3. Allow the iPad to go to sleep for an arbitrary period of time
4. Wake the iPad
5. Select the tab that your web application is in

My experience has been that the entire web application is reloaded AND the session cookie(s) are set to **null**.

Does anyone know why this occurs and more importantly, how to prevent it?